# Image is not displayed using ditto/doclister

Tags: image, modx, ditto

The website in on Modx Evo CMS. I tried using both DocLister and Ditto and none of them display image.
this is the chunk code with the tv [*image-blog*]:

```
    <div class="entry-img">
        <a class="img-popup" href="[+url+]">
            <img src="[*image-blog*]">
        </a>
    </div>

[[Ditto? &tpl=`article_tpl` &parents=`2` ]]

[[DocLister? 
&idType=`documents`
&tpl=`article_tpl`
&tvList=`image-blog`]]

[(rb_base_url)] - /assets, 
[(rb_base_dir)] - [(base_path)]assets/
<base href="[(site_url)]"/> is included in head.
```

Can't find another reason for not seeing the pic on the page..

Answer (score 0):

I found where the problem was. Maybe it will be useful for someone else:)
I made the tpl code look like that:

```
        <img src="[+tv.image-blog+]">
```

and DocLister worked!
Good day to everyone;-)